# onclick triggered automatically - how to create button on the fly

Tags: javascript

I tried to search through similar questions but I can't get a solution.

I have a snippet of code which is creating some HTML to append to a div:

```
      var list="<ul>";
      for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

        sid=data[i].sid;
        list += "blablabla <a onclick=delete(sid)>delete</a></li>";
      }
      list +="</ul>";
      document.getElementById("my_container").innerHTML = list;
```

The function delete(sid):

```
function delete(Sid){
  doSomething(taskSid,
  function(error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
        console.log(error.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log("deleted");
}
);
```

The problem is that the function delete(sid) is called automatically.
I have read that it's because I am calling directly the function, and I have tried different proposed solutions, but cannot really make them work.

My code will create a several rows which have this button or link which need to call the function delete.

Probably it is completely wrong also the approach of having one container and define the list in javascript?
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post full code as your second snippet looks incomplete

Answer (score 1):

You should try binding the function

```
<a onclick=delete.bind(null,sid)>delete</a>
```

Something like this bind prepares your listener to be executed here you are calling the function so because of that it get executed right away. You can also try arrow function here and calling delete function from inside it, like this

```
<a onclick=()=>delete(sid)>delete</a>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

you can refer to this for bind function

Answer (score 1):

Better approach is to use `createElement` method. Something like this:

```
let list = document.createElement('ul');
for(i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
   let sid=data[i].sid;
   let link = document.createElement('li');
   link.innerHTML = 'delete';
   link.onclick = function(){
      deleteTask(sid);
   };
   list.appendChild(link);
}
document.getElementById("my_container").appendChild(list);
```

Comment: thanks, I am following this approach but it looks like it has problem with the argument I pass in the function doSomething(sid).

Comment: You must apply function `doSomething` to your code. I don't know purpose of this function. You have incomplete code.

Comment: Yes sorry, what I mean is that it looks like passing always the last sid of the loop in the onClick of the button. The doSomething works, but the sid which gets is wrong. It's a different issue I reckon :)

Comment: Ok i have solved.. not sure if there is a better way to do it:

link.onclick = (function(sid){
              return function(){
                deleteTask(sid);
                }
            })(sid);

Comment: oh great it's simplified a lot. So it looks the problem was that I was not creating the new variable at each loop. Need lot of learning still. Thank you!